# Rviz crashes when loading stl files on ubuntu mate

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I’m running ROS kinetic on ubuntu mate by using Raspberry Pi 3

I tried to activate OpenGL but the process not complete

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/tutorial-activate-opengl-driver-for-ubuntu-mate-16-04/7094

What’s the best way to run ROS by Raspberry Pi 3 with full functionality?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367554/rviz-crashes-when-loading-stl-files-on-ubuntu-mate/) by [Moneera Banjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/60255/moneera-banjar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2020-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moneera Banjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/60255/moneera-banjar/) on 2020-12-16**:
I summarized all the attempts in this wiki page

https://github.com/mn-banjar/ROS_on_RaspberryPi3/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue is solved by upgrading to Ubuntu mate 18.04 and ROS melodic

---

Originally posted by [Moneera Banjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/60255/moneera-banjar/) with karma: 108 on 2021-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0